# Is it true that f (n) = Θ(f (n))?

Tags: reflection, time-complexity, big-o

Can you prove using reflexivity that f(n) equals big Theta(f(n))? It seems straight forward when thinking about it because f(n) is bounded above and below by itself. But how will I write this down? And does this apply to big Omega and big O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are intending to ask is (w.r.t. @emory:s answer) is something along the lines:

> *"For some function `f(n)`, is it true that `f ∈ ϴ(f(n))`?"*

If you emanate from the formal definition of Big-ϴ notation, it is quite apparent that this holds.

---

> **`f ∈ ϴ(g(n))`**
>
> ⇨ For some positive constants `c1`, `c2`, and `n0`, the following holds:
>
> ```
> c1 · |g(n)| ≤ |f(n)| ≤ c2 · |g(n)|, for all n ≥ n0          (+)
> ```

Let `f(n)` be some arbitrary real-valued function. Set `g(n) = f(n)` and choose, e.g., `c1=0.5`, `c2=2`, and `n0 = 1`. Then, naturally, `(+)` holds:

```
0.5 · |f(n)| ≤ |f(n)| ≤ 2 · |f(n)|, for all n ≥ 1
```

Hence, `f ∈ ϴ(f(n))` holds.

Answer (score 0):

No we can not because it is not true.  `ϴ(f(n))` is a set.  `f(n)` is a member of that set. `f(n)+1` is also a member of that set.